# Can't open SSIS package made in SSDT 15.5.X /15.6.0

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, ssis, etl, sql-server-data-tools

Can't open SSIS package made in SSDT 15.5.X /15.6.0.

Current version of VS is 15.6.1. It is stated that my solution is incompatible (please refer to the screenshot).

I tried creating new test SSIS packages, saving and opening them. However, this older one does not work.

Please help with this porblem and/or suggest some possible workaround to open the package.

[image]

Comment: Share the exact text of the error message, please.

Comment: @Brian, there is no error message. It is just stated that the package is incompatible as on the screenshot above.

Comment: Sorry - I missed that the first time I looked at the picture.  I get a similar message sometimes when upgrading SSRS packages, which is caused by a leftover configuration file - it has an extension of .user, as I recall.  Check what configuration files your "created new" projects contain and see if there are any extensions in the "upgraded" projects that don't match up, and try deleting those (or tacking on an extra extension so that VS doesn't try to open them).

Answer (score 1):

I restored my SSIS solution in the following way:

1. Created a new SSIS solution.
2. Inside the new solution I created blank packages with the same names as in my old one.
3. Copied all the content from old .dtsx package files into newly created blank .dtsx files.
4. Reopened the new solution.

Comment: To take the learning further.... it would be interesting to compare your new project file with your old one (in a text editor)

Answer (score 0):

I think I had a similar problem, I was trying to open the project as a file instead of clicking 'Open Project / Solution' from the VS2017 Start Page then navigating to the project. HTH.